# Defining function in terms of previously defined symbol

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

With a very high frequency I find myself working with giant and hard to alter expressions in a situation where it would be convenient to do something like

```
function = x^2;

f[x_]:= function;
```

which obviously doesn't work. I have also tried using `InputForm[function]` which does not work either.

How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f,x]
function = x^2;
f[x_] = function;
DownValues[f]  (* {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x^2} *)


ClearAll[f]
f[x_] := x^2;
DownValues[f]  (* {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x^2} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you encountered is due to the evaluation algorithm used by
Mathematica. In the documentation of `SetDelayed` is this statement

> SetDelayed has attribute HoldAll, rather than HoldFirst.

What this means is that you **do** want the RHS to be evaluated in your case.
As usual, you can force this by using `f[x_]:=Evaluate[function]` or else by using
the alternate `Set` function with `f[x_]=function`. In the usual situation such
as `f[x_]:=x^2` we **do** want to RHS to be held unevaluated until the function
is called. In your case `function` is a symbol which, **only** when evaluated, becomes
the `x^2` that you want in the function definition.

The decision to use `=` instead of `:=`  is a matter of preference and
convenience but it is context dependent.
For example, in the case of `function=x^2` you have to ensure that the symbol,
in this case `x`, does **not** have a value, otherwise `function` will use that
value which is **not** what you want. You have to remember to use
`ClearAll[x]` or `x=.` before using `x` to remove any value that `x` has.
If you use the standard `f[x_]:=x^2` then this is automatically taken care of.
You will run into the same problem if you use `f[x_]=x^2` and forget to use `:=`
instead because if `x` has a value then that value
will be used in the function
definition and that is almost certainly
**not** what you want.

Comment: Thank you!!! Now, what would be the threats of using Set instead of SetDelayed while routinely defining functions?

Comment: @GaloisFan - If the symbols used in the definition of the function have previously been given values, using `Set` will not do what you expect. Evaluate `Clear["Global\`*"]; x = 2; f[x_] = x^2; f[3]`